# Outlook 2016 blocking 4th and 5th mouse buttons (back/forw)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, logitech-setpoint

I remaps the 2 side (4th/5th) mouse buttons using Logitech SetPoint to Copy/Paste. But when I am using Outlook 2016 on Windows 10, I found that their functions are disabled. I can't find anything in the Options that relates. Plus, the side buttons do not seem to do anything inside Outlook.

[image]

I tried remapping the 4th/5th buttons to something else and they also have no effect. So it seems Outlook is blocking the buttons. Anyway to get around that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Microsoft Office adds its own short cuts to SetPoint!

[image]

[image]

By disabling the application-specific settings or replacing the specific button functions for each app, I can use my custom buttons again.

(Note that removing the office applications from the setting does not work as they will be added back.)

Comment: Glad to see that your issue has been resolved. Congratulations!

Comment: would you mind marking your own reply as the answer of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Can these custom mouse buttons work in other Office programs such Word or Excel? Not quite sure if your mouse custom feature has a good compatibility along with Microsoft Office programs. I would suggest you to contact the Logitech support to confirm this firstly.

By the way, according to my search, conflict with some existing Office shortcuts might cause similar issues. Please check the settings in this similar threads and see if they could help:

[Logitech mouse & excel](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/logitech-mouse-excel/c2e37d2a-76b5-461b-aa9a-c59da383c5ac)

[Problems using customised mouse button](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_other-mso_win10-mso_365hp/problems-using-customised-mouse-button/a7218eab-2a41-415d-b7ac-786ce4e2a389)

Comment: The custom copy/paste function also does not work in Word and Excel. I will try the Logitech Options to see if it works any better.